# How to retrieve an IShellItem's file size?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Given an `IShellItem*`, how can I find out its size?

When looking around, I've seen that a solution for this can be:

1. bind `IShellItem2` to the given `IShellItem`
2. retrieve the `IShellItem` property store
3. with [this function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propvarutil/nf-propvarutil-propvarianttouint64) (as seen in the example in the page), find the file's size

I don't fully understand the Win32 API, so maybe I got this all wrong, but if I am right I just find it difficult to get past the 1st step - How can I bind those two?

Comment: `IShellItem2` derives from `IShellItem`, so there is no need to "bind `IShellItem2` to the given `IShellItem`". You can call `IShellItem::BindHandler()` (and other `IShellItem` methods) directly on an `IShellItem2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use [IPropertyStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nn-propsys-ipropertystore) if you have an [IShellItem2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem2) reference, you can directly use [IShellItem2::GetUInt64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem2-getuint64) . Here is some sample code:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

...

IShellItem2* item;
if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\myPath\\myFile.ext", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item))))
{
  ULONGLONG size;
  if (SUCCEEDED(item->GetUInt64(PKEY_Size, &size))) // include propkey.h
  {
    ... use size ...
  }
  item->Release();
}

...

CoUninitialize();
```

If you already have an `IShellItem` reference (in general you want to get an `IShellItem2` directly) and want a `IShellItem2`, you can do this:

```
IShellItem2* item2;
if (SUCCEEDED(item->QueryInterface(&item2)))
{
    ... use IShellItem2 ...
}
```

Another way of doing it, w/o using `IShellItem2`, is this:

```
IShellItem* item;
if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\myPath\\myFile.ext", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item))))
{
  IPropertyStore* ps;
  if (SUCCEEDED(item->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_PropertyStore, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ps))))
  {
    PROPVARIANT pv;
    PropVariantInit(&pv);
    if (SUCCEEDED(ps->GetValue(PKEY_Size, &pv)))  // include propkey.h
    {
      ULONGLONG size;
      if (SUCCEEDED(PropVariantToUInt64(pv, &size))) // include propvarutil.h
      {
        ... use size ...
      }
      PropVariantClear(&pv);
    }
    ps->Release();
  }
  item->Release();
}
```

Comment: And how can I get IShellItem2 from an IShellItem?

Comment: `QueryInterface()`?  That's usually what you have to do in cases like this.

Comment: @avi Basic familiarity with the [component object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) is crucial for any Shell programming.

Comment: I'll def look into that, thanks!